YDSE with a beam of two wavelengths
Suppose I conduct Young's double slit experiment with a beam of light which has two wavelengths, say $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ (prototypically, $\lambda_1=560 nm, \lambda_2=640nm$). Is it true that a net dark fringe is obtained only at the position where the dark fringes due to both of the wavelengths coincide? Or can a dark fringe be obtained at the location of dark fringe for $\lambda_1$ and bright fringe for $\lambda_2$, or vice-versa? What decides the intensity of light in such a case?
Here's an example of a question that may clear it up. If I remember right, this is a question from an Indian high school examination paper, which asks that if a beam of light of two wavelengths 4000 Å and 6000 Å is used in YDSE, what is the least distance from the central maximum where a dark fringe is obtained. Now, the usual way of calculation of equating the $y_n$ expressions for dark fringes (with destructive interference) doesn't work.
I figured through a bit of calculation that the only possibility of a common fringe appearing for both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ in the above question is when the dark fringe of $\lambda_1$ and bright fringe of $\lambda_2$ is taken into account. Help me understand the concept here.
P.S.: I've come across a very crude explanation for taking LCM of $y_1$ and $y_1'$ (dark fringe distances from central maximum for individual $\lambda$) for both the wavelengths. I am looking for a different explanation though.
P.P.S.: The question problem above is not about the coincidence of the two dark fringes.

Both wavelengths are in the UV, so your eyes won’t see anything…

Ah sorry, ignore the prototypical example. I meant to say 560 nm and 640 nm. Let me edit it out. The example problem should be proper.

It's a nice math problem but it is NOT physics, most textbooks are based on the 1930s understanding!  In truth we know photons never cancel ... every photon behaves on its own .... the DSE apparatus has modes .. where light can go.  All you get is 2 overlapping color patterns.

@PhysicsDave I agree!

The photons don't interact with each other. Photons of one wavelength will make a pattern with a certain spacing of dark and light bands, and photons with a different wavelength, will make a pattern with a different spacing. If your light souce emits photons with more than one wavelength, then the image on the screen simply will be the sum of the patterns for each of the different wavelengths.

It's known that photons don't interact, but is a dark and bright fringe appearing "one on top of the other" grouped into a dark fringe? I guess that's what I wanted to mean.

@Newnitz, you can find out for yourself what it means for beams of light to be summed by shining two or more flashlights on a white wall in a dark room.
